# Unnest strange dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unnest

I need to create a df with certain columns from a non structured data base downloaded to a csv file where a column (by_month) has this strange dict in every row:

input:

```
                              by_month
dict_items([('11', 15865), ('12', 13235), ('1', 6398), ('2', 32258), ('3', 1160)])
 dict_items([('10', 299),  ('12', 2324),  ('11', 6689), ('1', 4332), ('2', 4352)])
```

desired output:

```
 10     11      12      1     2     3

nan   15865  13235    6398  32258   1160
299    6689  2324     4332   4352   nan
```

I need to create one column for every key (the number between '')

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide more details relevant to the problem and create a reproducible example.

Comment: Can you provide a simple input and desired output ?